# Transaction log backup impact on CPU

Tags: sql-server, performance, transaction-log

I had a serious CPU bottleneck 24/24 (it reaches 100% very often) for some weeks. The application has a pure aggressive OLTP (a thousand of query that retrieves often 1 row based on several joins).

This week I decided to begin a backup of the transaction log file, and hopefully the CPU bottleneck disappears.

Is there a direct relation between the transaction log file (size,backup or whatever) a the CPU bottleneck?

Comment: Every transaction is written to the log file, so clearing the log isn't going to do much. What else have you tried to identify the cause of the CPU bottleneck? What are the wait statistics? Power saving settings? SQL MAXDOP configuration?

Comment: You can see a small increase in CPU usage (particularly if you use compression) during log backups, but it is overall very insignificant. Rather you would want to address the queries that are executing. Find the one that's using the most CPU and work to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Backups of the transaction log will not help your CPU bottleneck.

1. How many deadlocks per hour or day do you have?
2. What is you CXPACKET wait value?
3. How much blocking do you have?

I am not saying to stop your transaction log backups, I am saying that this won't help the CPU bottleneck.